# S3Client of AWS Node.js SDK v3 only sends limited number of GetObjectCommand

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I tried to get all objects in AWS S3 bucket using @aws-sdk/client-s3.
Instead of getting 1000 object the program exits after 50 object downloads.

In while() loop the `obj_list.Contents.length` is equal to 1000 but
the process exits after receiving responses of 50 GetObjectCommand objects.

```
import { S3Client, ListObjectsV2Command, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"

(async () => {
    const client = new S3Client({
        credentials:{
            accessKeyId:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            secretAccessKey:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        },
    
        region: "us-east-1"
    })

    const input = {
        Bucket: 'Bucket-Name'
    }
    const cmd = new ListObjectsV2Command(input)
    const obj_list = await client.send(cmd)

    let i = 0
    while (i < obj_list.Contents.length) {
            const command = new GetObjectCommand({
                Bucket: 'Bucket-Name',
                Key: obj_list.Contents[i++].Key
            })
            client.send(command)
                .then(
                    (data) => {
                        console.log(`Content length: ${data.ContentLength}`)
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        const { requestId, cfId, extendedRequestId } = error.$$metadata
                        console.log(`Error: ${requestId}, ${cfId}, ${extendedRequestId}`)
                    }
                )
    }
    
    console.log("Done")
})();

console.log("End")
```

Here is the output in Visual Studio Code console:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\test.js
End
Done
50
Content length: 38535294
```

What are the possible reasons of that?

UPD. Here is the code which creates array of Promises 10 by 10, resolve these Promises then create another slice.
No difference - after 50 requests the script exits with status 13:
"Process exited with code 13".

The statuses of all resolved Promises are 'fulfilled'.

```js
// <list> contains all objects fom the bucket as in the code above
// ...
const step = 50
let i = 0 
while (i < obj_list.Contents.length)  {
    const to = Math.min(i + step, obj_list.Contents.length)
    let promises = []
    for (let f = i; f < to; ++f) {
        promises.push(client.send(
            new GetObjectCommand({
                Bucket: 'Bucket',
                Key: obj_list.Contents[f].Key
            })
        ))
    }
    const statuses = await Promise.allSettled(promises)
    i = to
}
```

This code exits on `await Promise.all(promises)` with exit code 13:

```
const promises = obj_list.Contents.map(async (obj_cont) => {
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: 'Bucket',
        Key: obj_cont.Key
    })
    const data = await client.send(command)
  });

const statuses = await Promise.all(promises)
```

Terminal output:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\async_batch.js
Process exited with code 13
```

Comment: Did you check output in test.js?

Comment: Ankush Jain, yes I did. the output is under the issue description
It prints the following:

End
Done 
50 Content length: 38535294

"50" means that "Content length: 38535294" was printed 50 times, because all objects have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you are missing `await` before the `send` method.

```
await client.send(command);
```

Refer this example - [List objects in an Amazon S3 bucket using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_ListObjects_section.html)

Comment: Isn't await similar to .then() ?
The send(command) returns a Promise object.

Comment: No, read [Awaiting a promise to be fulfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#awaiting_a_promise_to_be_fulfilled)

Comment: .then is a asynchronous callback, your loop is finishing because you are creating asynchronous task and the main thread doesn't know about them... Worth reading this article too: https://javascript.info/microtask-queue

Comment: I tried 'await' as well. No difference - after 50 requests the script exits with status 13:
"Process exited with code 13"

Comment: 13 Unfinished Top-Level Await: await was used outside of a function in the top-level code, but the passed Promise never resolved. Refer https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#exit-codes

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this exact problem today and it took me ages to work out what could be causing such odd behaviour, as my script was also exiting after 50 executions of the loop with error "Process exited with code 13".

I've used the AWS S3 Client many times in the past for long running processes and never hit this problem before.

What got me to the answer in the end was inspecting the response from the `GetObjectCommand`, where I realised that the 'Body' content of the response was left unresolved.  In this instance, I wasn't actually after the content of the object, just the metadata and it seems that there is a limit to the number of requests you can leave unresolved before it exits (I'm sure someone cleverer that me can explain that better).

The solution for me was to simply read the `response.body` content (even though I wasn't going to use it) inside the loop as follows:

```
const response = await s3Client.send(
  new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: s3Bucket,
    Key: key,
  }),
);
const body = await response.Body.transformToString();
```

The script was then able to execute to completion. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update 2023-03-21

I created a working example on my GitHub. It can make it easier for you to compare/debug the code.

- https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/aws-sdk-v3-s3-client-parallel-or-sequence-execution

##### Parallel or Sequence exectution of AWS SDK v3 S3 Client

Example of how to use the AWS SDK v3 S3 client to upload files to S3 in parallel or sequence execution.

##### Requirements

- Run `npm install` to install the dependencies.
- Set the `BUCKET` environment variable to a random bucket name.
- Run `node bucket-create.js` to create the bucket.
- After you run this experiment you can run `node bucket-delete.js` to delete the bucket.

##### Parallel

Using `Promise.all` to upload files in parallel.

- [Create 1000 files in parallel](https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/aws-sdk-v3-s3-client-parallel-or-sequence-execution/blob/main/thousand-files-create-promise-all.js)
- [Delete 1000 files in parallel](https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/aws-sdk-v3-s3-client-parallel-or-sequence-execution/blob/main/thousand-files-delete-promise-all.js)

##### Sequence

Using `while` loop to upload files in parallel.

- [Create 1000 files in sequence](https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/aws-sdk-v3-s3-client-parallel-or-sequence-execution/blob/main/thousand-files-create-while-loop.js)
- [Delete 1000 files in sequence](https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/aws-sdk-v3-s3-client-parallel-or-sequence-execution/blob/main/thousand-files-delete-while-loop.js)

---

#### Original answer

This is happening because you are using the callback version of the Promise object within the loop:

```js
while (i < obj_list.Contents.length) {
  const command = // ...
  client.send(command)
    .then(
      (data) => {
        // callback
      },
      (error) => {
        // callback
      }
    )
}
```

The loop finishes before the JS event loop fires all the `.then` callbacks.

As suggested by @Ankush Jain, you can use `await` to resolve the promise:

```js
while (i < obj_list.Contents.length) {
  try {
    const command = // ...
    const data = await client.send //... code here
    console.log(`Content length: ${data.ContentLength}`);
  } catch (error) {
    const { requestId, cfId, extendedRequestId } = error.$$metadata
    //... code here
  }
}
```

This will trigger them sequentially.

If you need to perform the requests in parallel, you can create an array of promises and use `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled` to await for them.

```js
const promises = obj_list.Contents.map(async () => {
  const command = // ...
  const data = await client.send //... code here
}); // array of promises

await Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: I tried to use await and the array of Promises as well.
Even more, I made array of Promises slice by slice, resolve the slice and create the next one. No difference after 50 requests the script exits silently.

Comment: You need to use the await in both cases. I see you updated the description, but your loop is finishing before awaiting for the promises to resolve. You need "await Promise.all".

Comment: Sorry,  I copied old code. The same issue with 'await'.
Changed the update.

Comment: I created a working example at: https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/aws-sdk-v3-s3-client-parallel-or-sequence-execution, it can make it easier for you to compare/debug the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @oieduardorabelo.
I used the `GetObjectCommand` in your "thousand-files-create-promise-all.js" script  instead of `PutObjectCommand` and saw the same issue - after 50 downloads the script exits.
I added "type": "module" to the package.json to make the script runnable, otherwise Node.js complains about `import` keyword. I hope this is not a reason of the issue.

Comment: Feel free to run the demo I built in your local machine and see the behavior, It does create/delete 1k files in parallel. Are you sure there are no other details in your code (not shared in the description above) that are causing the issue?

Comment: I have no issues with creating and deleting of files. My question is about downloading.
I see the same issue here. 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/pull/4492

Comment: It could be a memory issue. I added the "thousand-files-get-promise-all.js" file with a video of it running on my local machine. The S3 client doesn't support batch-get. That is the only way to request multiple files in parallel today. Unfortunately, it can be specific to your environment/machine. I suggest spinning VM/Docker or a remote machine (EC2) and executing tests. Thanks for sharing the GitHub issue. I also use S3 Get with N parallels request without an issue in ECS/Lambda. Good luck!